# What does 'collateral' mean as a grammatical term

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In the OLD I find

> confīō ~fierī intr. (collateral with pass. of conficio) [con- + fīō]

In Bennett's grammar I find:

> The archaic and poetic Present Subjunctive forms duim, duint, perduit, perduint, etc., are not from the root da-, but from du-, a collateral root of similar meaning.

Doing some googling I found

> These words are collateral adjectives of Latin origin. These words are not etymologically related to their associated noun forms but are linked semantically.

Here [enter link description here](http:///https://englishtutorialedu.com/tag/collateral-adjectives-of-latin-origin/)

I can't tell exactly what 'collateral' means in these contexts.

Looking up the word in the OED I find

> 4.A.4 Descended from the same stock, but in a different line; pertaining to those so descended. Opposed to lineal.

So it seems that 'collateral' especially in the first instance means that 'confio' is related to the passive of 'conficio' but has a slightly different meaning.  Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty much what you quoted:

> These words are not etymologically related to their associated noun forms but are linked semantically.

*Fio* and *facio* are unrelated etymologically, but in practice *fio* has been adopted as the passive/intransitive of *facio*. Same with their prefixed forms.

The [wiktionary article on collateral adjectives in English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_collateral_adjectives) illustrates the same principle. The adjectival form of 'cow' is 'bovine', yet of course they're not at all etymologically related.

For understanding why the term '[collateral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collateral)' is chosen, it might help to think of its roots: *later-* from the Latin for 'side', so something that comes together (*con-*) from the side (*later-*) (as opposed to e.g. "direct").

Comment: Cool, thanks ...